# Angular laravel app start issue

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

[image]I am using angular for frontend and laravel for backend.

When I start the client angular app using below command:

```
ng serve --open  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

It loads js files from laravel backend public folder.

Angular requests (in browser console)

> GET http://localhost:4200/server/client/inline.655c959301e57e1e55b1.bundle.js return 404 not found or ::net::ERR_ABORTED

When I open it in browser without port, it loads.

I am using below proxy setting in angular:

```
{
  "/secure": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80/server",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/storage": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80/server",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why its request to

> server/client/...............

If you're using ng serve, it should be directed to

> http://localhost:4200/inline.655c959301e57e1e55b1.bundle.js

Check your routes path.

The proxy setting doesn't change any setting to the internal routes. Unless you try to access Angular webpack in Laravel Public directory, but it doesn't make sense.

Maybe you can try to build angular without proxy and put in Laravel public dir. See if it's working.